# Find two integers in the range [L R]

Tags: function, range, product, variable-assignment

Given two integers L and R, the task is to find the count of unordered pairs of integers (A, B) in the
range [L, R] such that the ratio of A and B is the same as the ratio of the product of digits of A and the
product of digits of B.

Comment: please provide code for c language

Comment: Examples:
Input: L = 10, R = 50
Output: 2
Explanation: The pairs in the range [10, 50] that follow the given condition are (15, 24) as 15 : 24 = 5 : 8 ≡
(1*5) : (2*4) = 5 : 4 and (18, 45) as 18 : 45 = 2 : 5 ≡ (1*8) : (4*5) = 8 : 20 = 2 : 5.
Input: L = 1, R = 100
Output: 43